# Batch file not getting the first 5 characters in drop file filename

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, xcopy

I created a simple batch file that copies drop file in specific folder. This my batch script:

```
rem This will create a BACK-UP DATA Folder in Desktop
rem with a SUB-FOLDER which filename must be the first 5 characters of drop file filename
rem with another folder filename: "COPY" inside (just for another back up)
for %%f in (%1) do (
    set oldName=%%~nf
    set newName=%oldName:~0,5%
    mkdir %HOMEPATH%\Desktop\"BACK-UP DATA"\"%newName%"\
    mkdir %HOMEPATH%\Desktop\"BACK-UP DATA"\"%newName%"\COPY 
    xcopy %%f "%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\BACK-UP DATA\%newName%"
    rem will copy drop file also inside COPY folder
    xcopy %%f "%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\BACK-UP DATA\%newName%\COPY"
    rem open created folder
    start "" "%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\BACK-UP DATA\%newName%\"
    PAUSE
)
```

This is the output in command prompt...

```
set oldName="New Text Document"
 set newName=~0,5
  mkdir C:\User\username\Desktop\"BACK-UP DATA"\""\
  mkdir C:\User\username\Desktop\"BACK-UP DATA"\""\COPY
  xcopy "C:\User\username\Desktop\New Text Document.txt" "C:\User\username\Desktop\BACK-UP DATA\"
  xcopy "C:\User\username\Desktop\New Text Document.txt" "C:\User\username\Desktop\BACK-UP DATA\\COPY"
  start "" "C:\User\username\Desktop\BACK-UP DATA\\"
  pause
```

Why the variable `%newName%` doesn't work? What's wrong in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want to declare variables and use this same variables inside for loops or if's you have to use [delayed Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) ex:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Also you have to substitute `%` by `!`

```
set "oldName=%%~nf"
set "newName=!oldName:~0,5!"
mkdir "%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\BACK-UP DATA\!newName!\COPY"
```

Comment: Edit Note: you don't need the \third line when used \third with the \fourth line, 
and you never know what characters are in the names, so use "" in the "variables"